# Fastest way to compute a matrix distance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have to compute a distance between two matrix. The distance is the sum of the squared differences between matching points.

Here is matrix A

```
[{'id': 1, 'feature': 17}, {'id': 3, 'feature': 1},{'id': 18, 'feature': 26}]
```

Here is matrix B:

```
[{'id': 4, 'feature': 3}, {'id': 1, 'feature': 183},{'id': 17, 'feature': 9},{'id': 18, 'feature': 19},{'id': 123, 'feature': 2}]
```

The distance is:

```
(17-183)^2 + (26-19)^2 = 27 605
```

With my level of Python, I would do:

```
s = 0
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if(a['id']==b['id']):
            s+=(a['feature']-b['feature'])*(a['feature']-b['feature'])
```

And I get the good result.

But I will do this operation on large matrixes and many times.

Question is: what is the fastest way to code that in Python?

Comment: use numpy module - it is almost as fast as equivalent c code. Matrix operations are best done using numpy

Comment: Figuring out if your matrices are sparse or dense will also make a difference (those you gave in the example are sparse).

Comment: You've tagged the question with `django`, so *assuming* this data is coming from a SQL database, you could also compute this in a SQL query using a `JOIN` on `id` and aggregating using `sum()`.

Comment: @JashandeepSohi: good idea. I haven't found the way to do it with Queries (A.id_set__in=B.id_set not working)

Comment: You could always write the raw SQL query: `SELECT sum((a.feature - b.feature)^2) FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.id;`